# Connect car speakers to 2 separate head units

Tags: audio, speakers, head-unit

How can i connect 4 car door speakers to 2 separate head units I'm thinking of using diodes any one has any clues please provide a diagram with type and rating of the diodes or any possible alternatives thank you

Comment: Diodes are not going to help you here.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the ultimate goal of hooking the two head units into the speakers?

Comment: Diodes in the audio path are going to make the system sound terrible.

Answer (score 1):

There are switches available for swapping between sets of speakers : check out the HiFi world - you can use these to switch between two head units.

Depending on the type of switch you may be able to switch only the supply from either head unit and common the relevant returns. However, if both head units are powered then you may have interference issues.